# How do I show a list of all the test failures after completion of a gradle task involving tests

Tags: testing, gradle

After running gradle tasks that include tests on my multi-module project, I want to see a summary of every test failure across all modules, e.g.

```
module 1:

testmodule1thing1 PASSED
testmodule1thing2 FAILED

results
2 tests 1 passed 1 failed

module 2:
testmodule2thing1 PASSED
testmodule2thing2 FAILED

results
2 tests 1 passed 1 failed

module 3:
testmodule3thing1 FAILED

results
1 tests 1 passed 1 failed

BUILD FAILED

========= I already have everything above this line

test failures:
testmodule1thing1
testmodule2thing2
testmodule3thing1

========= I want everything between the last line and this line
```

Is this possible? If so, how? If a full task summary isn't possible, I can live with a per-module summary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a testlistener in combination with the buildFinished hook for that. A very simple solution can look like this first draft:

```
allprojects {
    // add a collection to track failedTests
    ext.failedTests = []

    // add a testlistener to all tasks of type Test
    tasks.withType(Test) {
        afterTest { TestDescriptor descriptor, TestResult result ->
            if(result.resultType == org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestResult.ResultType.FAILURE){
                failedTests << ["${descriptor.className}::${descriptor.name}"]
            }
        }
    }

    // print out tracked failed tests when the build has finished
    gradle.buildFinished {
        if(!failedTests.empty){
            println "Failed tests for ${project.name}:"
            failedTests.each { failedTest ->
                println failedTest
            }
            println ""
        }
    }
}
```

Another option to have better visibility for your failed tests is maybe using gradle build scans (https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.gradle.build-scan).

Answer (score 10):

This can also be accomplished directly within the *test* task itself:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    // a collection to track failedTests
    ext.failedTests = []

    afterTest { descriptor, result ->
        if (result.resultType == TestResult.ResultType.FAILURE) {
            String failedTest = "${descriptor.className}::${descriptor.name}"
            logger.debug("Adding " + failedTest + " to failedTests...")
            failedTests << [failedTest]
        }
    }

    afterSuite { suite, result ->
        if (!suite.parent) { // will match the outermost suite
            // logs each failed test
            if (!failedTests.empty) {
                logger.lifecycle("Failed tests:")
                failedTests.each { failedTest ->
                    logger.lifecycle("${failedTest}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```